# More efficient way to calculate direction on both axis?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a Vector3 defined like so {x,y,z};

I want to get the angles of the point relative to the y axis and the origin.

I do:

```
  float tilt = atan2( point.z(), point.y() );
  float pan = atan2( point.x(), point.y() );
```

Now, I need the directions so the dot product is not interesting.

Is there a better way to get those values in one go?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "relative directions"?

Comment: I meant direction, let me correct that. I need to know whether it is negative or positive, which atan2 tells. I basically need to know if there is an alternative solution, but faster.

Comment: Direction cannot be positive or negative. Do you need semi-space relative to coordinate planes?

Comment: I need the angles in relation to the axis for a given point

Comment: To all: I don't even understand why you want to close that question. Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Expression

```
angle = acos(x / length(x,y,z))
```

gives angle between vector and OX axis. Range is `0..Pi`.

Perhaps you want `-Pi/2..Pi/2` range between OYZ plane and vector - in this case use `Pi/2-angle`

Comment: So basically I am down to two calculations to extract the angle of my point in comparison to the x axis and separately the z axis